# How to send push notification according to dateTime which is stored in database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I need conceptual help.
I've a web application in asp.net MVC that create schedule (just like reminder application) according to date time and store this information in database. Now I would like to send message to user on that date and time(not manually.
Users means mobile phone app (My created app) user, phone will receive push. user not concerned about my web application it a control panel.
Usually i send push notification manually to user device by running a script from web application, It can send instant notification but i need to send it according to time schedule automatically.
How can i do this???

Answer (score 1):

You need a task scheduling library for web application. define a task and run task in background for sending notification in desired intervals. For more info read [this post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) by Scot Hanselman.

Here is [top 20 NuGet packages](http://nugetmusthaves.com/Tag/tasks) for tasks.